# Is it normal for HikariPool to make 3 active connections on startup and never give them up?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hikaricp

Some relevant version numbers:

```
<spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<spring-data-jpa.version>1.7.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
```

When starting up my Spring application it takes up 3 active connections from the start and 1 is idle.

HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=4, active=3, idle=1, waiting=0)

And it stays like this forever. So actually only one connection is available to use since 3 are being used all the time.

This has to be atleast 4 to start. Without having it below 4 it fails to create some beans with AutoWired daos in them.

ds.setMaximumPoolSize(4);

Is it normal for application to take up 3 active connections and never release them. (Without using the application for example)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Deadpool Is it normal for application to take up 3 active connections and never release them. (Without using the application for example)

Comment: If it takes up connections, those connections are obtained. Make sure you don't obtain connections yourself and have properly configured hibernate. It is probably one of that that is not releasing connections.